# How to Capture Each New Millisecond Without Overwhelming the CPU

Tags: c#, loops, single-threaded

My requirement here is that I need to update time in Milliseconds continuously, so with each new millisecond elapsed, I need to capture that and write it to a file. I tried to run that in a while loop but I noticed that the program took more than 50% of CPU. I tried to add the method `Thread.Sleep(1)` at the end of each cycle and that caused some of milliseconds being skipped. Example:

1698281344731

1698281344747

1698281344762

1698281344778

1698281344794

Here is my code, would appreciate any advice that could steer me to the right direction.

```
 while (true)
 {
     long CurrentMS = GetMilliseconds();
     Writer(CurrentMS);
     Console.Write(CurrentMS + "\r\n");
     Thread.Sleep(1);
 }
```

Comment: writing costs also time like you can see

Comment: Advice that could steer you to right direction: you definitely don't need write something both to file and console every millisecond infinitely)

Comment: Writing something to screen at a rate faster than the screen's refresh is pointless. Anyway, the default resolution for Sleep is 15ms, depending on the Windows edition. It can be reprogrammed to 1ms with a [timeBeginPeriod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod) call, if needed - games and media apps often do that.

Comment: That is an absurd requirement, which you should reject. However if you really want to generate a list of numbers representing each millisecond, you could check the current time then iterate over each time value you missed before going to sleep again.

Answer (score 0):

You could offload the writing to happen only after you are done looping, or every x iterations. That would let you avoid any slowdowns that may by caused by writing to disk. The easiest way to do that would be to store your strings in a list, and then write them all out at the end.

Comment: I can offer an optimization suggestion to this: Just record the initial timestamp and then generate the following ones from that as you write them out :)